# Buildkite Windows agent - hook scripts location

Tags: hook, buildkite

Does anybody know where I should place my buildkite global hook scripts on a windows agent machine?

I place it in the `hooks` folder as specified in the buildkite-agent.cfg ... But it does not work. 
It works just fine when using an Ubuntu agent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hooks support](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/hooks) was added to the Windows release in Buildkite Agent version 3, which is currently in beta and available from the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/buildkite/agent/releases?prerelease=true). You need to download the latest beta.

You might also need to add `.bat` to the end of your hook file name, like `...\hooks\environment.bat`.

To export your environment variables make sure you use [`set`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx):

```
# ...\hooks\environment.bat

set FOO="bar"
```

Now in your job batch files or scripts you should be able to use the variable:

```
echo "%FOO%"

# outputs "bar"
```

Comment: I tried, but still cant get it to work...! I wonder if i still need to use `export`? or `set` as the windows command? the .bat file also needs to be run by admin rights for the envs to be set properly..!

Comment: If you're trying to change an environment variable, yes, make sure you do something like `set FOO "bar"` in the windows batch file.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a few more hints, too. :-)

Comment: Thank you sj26 , I just had to add a = sign for the set command to make it work